# Extract RTP sequence in big endian architecture

Tags: sequence, endianness, rtp

For extracting  the sequence number of a RTP header in a little endian architecture the following type is used
unsigned short seq = (packet[2] << 8) | packet[3];
In a big endian the following is right
unsigned short seq = (packet[3] << 8) | packet[2]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you use the same code on both architectures. It's the endian format of the data that matters, not the endianess of your CPU when you do it that way.

The RTP sequence number is stored with the most significant byte first and the least significant byte last according to the protocol specification. So if the sequence number is 0x1234 (or 4660 decimal), it will be stored in your 2 bytes `packet[2]` and `packet[3]` as

```
packet byte   0   1   2   3
             +---+---+---+---+
             |...|...|12 |34 |
             +---+---+---+---+
```

Now you want to extract byte 2 and place it as the most significant byte in the integer and byte 3 at the least significant, which is simply the code:

```
uint16_t seq = (packet[2] << 8) | packet[3];
```

This makes `seq` the value 0x1234 (or 4660 decimal) independent of the endianess of your CPU.